# Evaluating $ \binom{n}{0} + 2 \binom{n}{1} + 2^2 \binom{n}{2} + \dots + 2^k \binom{n}{k} + \dots + 2^n \binom{n}{n} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

With $n$ a positive integer, evaluate the sum
$$
\binom{n}{0} + 2 \binom{n}{1} + 2^2 \binom{n}{2} + \dots + 2^k \binom{n}{k} + \dots + 2^n \binom{n}{n}
$$

I'm pretty sure that this has to do with the binomial theorem which states that
$$
(a + b)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}b^k
$$
but I'm not sure how to apply it if that is indeed the case.

Comment: Take $a=2$ and $b=1$

Comment: The formula remains true if you take $a^k b^{n-k} $ instead of $a^{n-k} b^k$.

Comment: Ahh my goodness. I can't believe that I missed that. Thank you @Essaidi!